# struct and struct-type function in header file

Tags: c, struct, header

I am new to C and I want to include my struct in a header file however I am not sure if what I did below is correct or not. I am sure that I need the struct to be declared in the header file, just not sure about if it is the right way to declare the struct type function `search()`

```
#ifndef BTREE_H_INCLUDED
#define BTREE_H_INCLUDED

struct bin_tree {
    char serial[30];
    int socket;
    struct bin_tree * right, * left;
};

typedef struct bin_tree node;

node* search(node ** tree, char *val);

#endif
```

Comment: This looks perfectly OK. What's your question?

Comment: This might be better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: the `**` is suspicious :)

Comment: I think pointer to pointer to structure is always suspicious, even if person who wrote it didn't ask if it was done correctly:)

Answer (score 1):

> *"I am not sure if what I did below is correct or not"*

***It is.*** Just note that passing an address of pointer (i.e. `search` function taking `node ** tree`) makes sense in situations when you want your function to change the pointer. Semantically, `search` doesn't seem to be one of those functions :)

And the small (rather cosmetic) improvement might be changing:

```
struct bin_tree {
    char serial[30];
    int socket;
    struct bin_tree * right, * left;    // <-- avoid declaring pointers this way
};

typedef struct bin_tree node;
```

into a single `typedef`:

```
typedef struct node {
    char serial[30];
    int socket;
    struct node * right;
    struct node * left;
} node;
```

Comment: And it could perfectly well be `struct node` instead of using a different name for the `typedef` and the `struct` tag.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: That's actually good point since the *consistency* matters :)